# How to form a multipart form data request using AFNetworking 1.3.3

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I am using `AFNetworking` 1.3.3.

I need to make a `multipart/form-data` request to my server with image data and some other additional stuffs.

I have no clue how to format this multipart request. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the [project's GitHub page](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) (branch 1.x) you can find this example

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api-base-url.com"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.jpg"], 0.5);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/upload" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"avatar" fileName:@"avatar.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
}];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];
[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

You can also read the [documentation](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.3/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/multipartFormRequestWithMethod%3apath%3aparameters%3aconstructingBodyWithBlock%3a)

Comment: Actually I am using AFNetworking version 1.3.3 as I need to support iOS 5 also in my app. And I guess AFHTTPRequestOperationManager is not available in this version. Can you please tell me an alternative for this?

Comment: You didn't say it in your original question. Anyway I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I have also edited the question now. One more doubt.. Can you please let me know what does enqueueHTTPRequestOperation do?

Comment: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/1.3.3/Classes/AFHTTPClient.html#//api/name/enqueueHTTPRequestOperation

Comment: I can see that you have set the param dictionary to nil in your example. Can you tell me how can I use that dictionary?